# ASP.NET DragPanelExtender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, drag-and-drop

I have 3 colums with a lot of boxes in it.
I'm trying to drag all those different boxes. So far so good.
But I can't put them between two boxes, they're just in front of each other.
A second problem is that when the page refreshes the boxes are back on their begin position, but I want them on the new position till I move them again.

Can some one help me?

Thanks!

The code is on: [link text](http://www.bjornseigers.be/1.txt) because I had a problem with this editor and the ASP.NET code.